# How to configure .gitignore to ignore content folders from Android Studio on GitKraken?

Tags: android, android-studio, gitkraken

I am trying to create my `.gitignore` file to avoid that my GitKraken detects those files. I was able to avoid some of them but not all that I would like to ignore.

These are the files that I am not able to ignore:

- Files inside `.gradle/2.14.1/...` folder.
- File `.idea/workspace.xml`
- File `app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml`

Here is my `.gitignore` file:

```
.*
!/.gitignore
*.iml

#Gradle files
.gradle
.gradle/
build/

local.properties
/local.properties
/*/local.properties

/.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries

.DS_Store
.DS_Store?

/build
/*/build/
/*/*/build

/captures
captures/

.externalNativeBuild
```

How can I make that GitKraken ignores those files?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that you can't ignore them because them are already in the repository. Try removing them (saving a backup somewhere else). Then apply the .gitignore and commit it. As the last thing, re-add the elements, them won't be managed

Comment: @LucaNicoletti I have tried deleting the cache of those files as AlexTa pointed in his answer but the files are detected again when I restart Android Studio.

Comment: remove them, added them in .gitignore, push without staging the files

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove already tracked files from repository so .gitignore rules takes effect, execute the following commands for those files:

```
git rm path/to/file --cached
```

Comment: I have tried with this option but when I restart Android Studio the files are shown again at GitKraken.